# Return String with @ResponseBody JSON

Tags: jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to return a String from a handler method to be used in a callback from a $.getJSON call.

```
@RequestMapping("setLink")
public @ResponseBody String setLink(String username, String link) {
    service.setLink(username, link);
    return "link";
}
```

JSON call

```
$.getJSON("setLink", {username: username, link: link}, function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        });
```

The callback is not running. I think this could be because the String is not valid JSON, but I can find lots of examples of handler methods using @ResponseBody that are returning Strings without any problems.

Comment: `$.getJSON()` is a wrapper for `$.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ By using $.ajax you can specify dataType parameter. The default is string.

Comment: So are you saying that $.getJSON can not handle the value returned from a handler method annotated with @ResponseBody that returns String?

Answer (score 0):

$.get solved the problem for me.

It appears returning a simple String is not valid JSON.